# How to add stop button to control bar in video.js 5.2.4?

Tags: javascript, video.js

I can't understand how to do this. Can anyone help me?

I found this - http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/control-bar.html. Maybe it will help.

Comment: My codepen example - http://codepen.io/samsky/pen/wKLmZJ

Comment: What do you expect from a stop button? What does it do differently to the pause button?

Comment: If you are just looking to change the icon of the pause button to a stop icon that can be done via CSS.

Comment: @misterben I'm just want to add stop button after play button.